# What are the names of the Postal 2 Levels?

Tags: postal-2

I'm having great fun using cheats after completing the game on Hestonworld difficulty. I now want to fight the final boss, but don't want to have to play through the whole game to get there. There is a console command available to switch level: `goto (<level name>)`. This seems ideal, only I can't find the actual names of the individual levels anywhere. `goto sunday` does nothing, as does `goto boss` and `goto final_boss`. How can I skip to the final boss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to enable console commands, with `EnableDebugMenu`. [The steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/223470/discussions/0/558754259267311083/) reports that `sissy` may also work.

According to both the [IGN Postal 2 cheat page](http://au.ign.com/cheats/games/postal-2-pc-481847) and the [Game FAQ Postal 2 page](http://au.ign.com/cheats/games/postal-2-pc-481847), you can switch days by using the command `SetDate(int DayNumber)`, and switch days without changing objectives with the command `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`.

---

**Weekdays** are available with the regular Postal 2 game.

Monday -        `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`
Tuesday -       `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`
Wednesday - `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`
Thursday -     `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`
Friday -          `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`

**Weekend** is available to players playing with the [Apocalypse Weekend](http://postal.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse_Weekend) expansion.

Saturday -     `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`
Sunday -       `SetDate(int DayNumber)` | `WarpToDay(int DayNumber)`